# How to set RN171 module work on UDP?

Tags: communication

How to set RN171 module work on UDP?

[www.aisgps.com/udp.jpg http://www.aisgps.com/udp.jpg](http://www.aisgps.com/udp.jpg)

for i have look the user munual,but always failed.

Anyone knows how to set,pls give me some advices.
thanks.

Comment: You should show us what you've tried so far; it will provide clues about your present level of understanding.

Comment: The docs list in detail the exact setup for UPD. I use UDP with this module. Can you say specifically what you are having problems with?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the WiFly user manual, available [here](http://www.rovingnetworks.com/resources/download/93/WiFly_User_Manual), they have a section on "Sending data using UDP". The commands for setting it up are:

```
//enter CMD mode
//associate the network
set ip proto 1         // Enable UDP as the protocol
set ip host <address>  // Set the remote host’s IP address
set ip remote <value>  // Set the remote port on which the host listens
set ip local <value>   // Set the port number on which the module listens
save                   // Save the settings in the configuration file
reboot                 // Reboot the module
```

If you're having other problems, please describe them.

Answer (score 0):

After you reboot the module, try to reconnect to the default SSID because it gets reset. That is what we do in order to send data to another computer